# Store an email address from a HTML form in a .txt file

Tags: php, html, text, form-submit

I have a simple HTML page and have a text entry box to capture email addresses for subscriptions. However, I cannot get the PHP part to work and store the address in the text file.

```
<!-- Signup Form -->
<form id="signup-form" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
    <?php if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            if ($email == ''){ echo Email is empty! }
            if($email != ''){
                $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
                fwrite($myfile, "Email:". $email);
                fclose($myfile);
            }
        }
    ?>
</form>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php is a good start. Which I might add will throw you an undefined submit index notice.

Comment: and `{ echo Email is empty! }` another error; a parse error.

Comment: You code is good, you ust need to change this `<input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />` to this `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" />`

Comment: @Hackerman It's not good, look `if ($email == ''){ echo Email is empty! }`

Comment: I missed that...and also I assume that it's a typo...